# Get screen name - twython

Tags: python, api, twitter, twython

Total noob to this. I have set up a script that can send a tweet, all I want to do is print text before the enter message promt that displays the screen name of the account.

In my mind it would be something like

```
user_name = twitter.get_screen_name()

print(user_name)
```

I have loaded all the keys from my app etc.

I notice on varify_credentials it does have

```
u'screen_name': screenname
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already note, [`verify_credentials`](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/basic_usage.html#user-information) returns a representation of the user that includes both `name` and `screen_name`. Therefore your method could look like:

```
def get_screen_name(twitter):
    return twitter.verify_credentials()["screen_name"]
```

Then you can call it:

```
user_name = get_screen_name(twitter)
print(user_name)
```

Making this a method of the `twitter` instance of the `Twython` class would be more complicated.